# Generating Certificate Chain using OpenSSL

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate

I tried creating a certificate chain, by creating a Root certificate and then two levels of intermediate certificate. But i do not find the chain details in certification path.

I generated the root certificate using the below command:-

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgCA_RootKey.key -genkey
openssl req -new -x509  -key  D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgCA_RootKey.pem  -out  D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgCA_RootCertificate.pem -days 3650
```

And the intermediate certificates as below:-

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.key -genkey
openssl req -new  -key D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.key -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.csr -CA D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgCA_RootCertificate.crt -CAkey D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgCA_RootKey.key  -set_serial 01 -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.crt

openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_a1.key -genkey
openssl req -new  -key D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_a1.key -out D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_a1.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_a1.csr -CA D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.crt -CAkey D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_1.key -set_serial 02 -out  D://Demo//Certificates//SSL//orgIA_a1.crt
```

But the certificate path is not correct. The certificate path shows only the issed to. The chain is not getting set.
I am looking at the generating a client certificate having the below chain:(chain length 3)
Root--> intermediate1-->intermediate2-->client certificate.

Now my client certificate shows only itself in the chain details.
Any help is appreciated as I am new to openSSL.

**Update** 
Tried validating the certificate path for intermediate2 certificate. But it fails saying that unable to validate certificate path. Is there anything woring in the way i am genertaing the mutiple levels of intermediate certificate.

Comment: is it a self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes..I am only trying to be the Root CA. And the Root CA certificate is self signed. The intermediate1 is signed by root CA and intermediate2 is signed by intermediate1.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificates chains are not known to openssl as they are self-signed.
You need to include all your intermediates/Root bundle (-CApath) in the command-line.